# Gradle build not finished

Tags: android

I have android studio 2.2.2,the gradle keeps on running for more than 12 hours.

I have the gradle version of 2.2.0,and I have uninstalled and re-installed the studio still it is not working.Anyone please help.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: add errors and screenshots!!

Comment: there is no error im getting.It keeps on building

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle
Check the 'Offline work' under 'Global Gradle settings' This will help you reduce the time

Comment: I have made that too,also I have done clearing caches from android studio

Comment: can you post your gradle file

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
 }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'lib'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: @Abilash I also have the same problem. The build process is running for an hour. When I enable the offline work mode, solves my problem.

Comment: @Madhan I have done that many times still it doesnt seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

It happens once in a while, just kill the Java process from task manager and gradle with stop with a error message at the top right corner of AStudio, ignore this error. You APK is ready but you'll have to install it manually(copy paste to your device).

`gradle --stop` will, sometimes, only add up a new task in task queue.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `gradle --stop` from the command line. It kills all gradle processes.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your build with --profile from the command line as described here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html